# How to get the data out of ajax requests in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The structure of my program is as follows:

```
var output = [];  //<---- where I want to store the data 

function getData(){
    for(...){
        $.getJSON("...", function(data){
            if(...){
                output.push(data[...]);
            }else{
                $.getJSON("...", function(data2){
                    output.push(data2[...]);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This doesn't work due to what I understand to be the async nature of the ajax calls. I can't access the data after calling the function. Doing output[0] returns undefined.

Comment: If you could link your full code + what your data looks like. Why is it nested inside of a `for loop` ? That's generally not a good practice.

Comment: In this case you have to work with promises, if you really need the calls to be executed in a loop..

Comment: "Doing output[0] returns undefined."  It will before the `getJSON` function returns, yeah.  You need to access the data inside the callback, or else return a promise from the callback and wait for it to resolve before trying to access the data.

Comment: (You probably don't need to be calling `getJSON` inside a loop, unless you're requesting different endpoints on each iteration. If the data you're trying to retrieve is an array, just call it once and put the returned array in your output.)  (If you *are* calling different endpoints and pushing each of them into your output array separately, be aware that they will wind up in a random order depending on which requests happen to return first.)

Comment: @ChristopherMesser the loop is to loop through a list of name that gets used in the url for the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *initiate* the requests in a loop synchronously but you have to listen for the responses *asynchronously*.
jQuery's getJSON method returns a jqXHR object which is Promise compatible. So, you can use Promise.all like this:

```
function getData() {
  var requests = [];

  for (...) {
    const request = $.getJSON(...);
    requests.push(request);
  }

  return Promise.all(requests);
}

getData().then(function (results) {
  // results is an array with responses of your requests (ordered by push order)   
});
```